# php + mysql still commiting

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 mysql queries that I execute from php, 1 is successful and 2 are not. I have however set a commit and rollback. When I do a var_dump on the the commit it returns true, the query that is successful inserts the value in the db instead of rolling back.

//connection is established

```
function __construct() {

    $this->error['State']=0;
    $this->error['Msg']="";

    try {
        $db_con=mysqli_connect($this->server, $this->dbuname, $this->dbpassw, $this->database);
        $this->db_connection=$db_con;
        mysqli_autocommit($db_con,FALSE);
        mysqli_begin_transaction($this->db_connection);         
    }

    catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->setError("Error: Please try again");
    }

}
```

//query and commit

```
public function result($sql) {

    try {
        $result=mysqli_query($this->db_connection,$sql);
        if($result) {
            $this->result=$result;
        }else {
            $this->setError("Error: Please try again");
        }
    }

    catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->setError("Error: Please try again");
    }   

}//end of result function   

public function commit() {

    $mysqli=$this->db_connection;
    $c=mysqli_commit($mysqli);
    if (!$c) {
        $this->setError("Error: Please try again");
        mysqli_rollback($mysqli);
    }else{
        return 1;
    }

}
```

//query

```
public function make($i){

    $sql="INSERT INTO t1(tcol1, tcol2, tcol3) VALUES ";
    ...

    $this->commit();

    $this->close_conn();
```

Thanks

Comment: I encourage you to read what you wrote. You'll find that you never asked a question, only presented a situation.

Comment: point noted thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the tables were isam and the database was innoDB. When I changed the tables to innoDB it started working.

Answer (score -1):

If you tell it to commit it will commit.  It won't roll back just because there was an error in one of the statements.  You have to check for errors each time you perform a query and then rollback if there is an error.  Or just check at the end before committing:

```
public function commit() {

    $mysqli=$this->db_connection;
    if ($this->error['State'] === 0) {
        $this->setError("Error: Please try again");
        mysqli_rollback($mysqli);
    } else {
        $c = mysqli_commit($mysqli);
        if ($c) return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, thought that the commit had some sort of error checking mechanism.

Comment: Isn't the actual benefit of commit that it only executes the queries involved if they're correct?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld the benefit is that I can ensure that *either* all or none of my *valid* queries are executed.  If I'm doing a long, manual transaction, I might be an hour into writing different queries and accidentally spell "INSERT" wrong.  I'll get an error message.  I don't want to start over, I just fix the typo and keep working.  If I get to a point where I realize the way I did it isn't going to work, I can rollback.  If I see that everything looks good, I can commit.  There are plenty of use cases where you might get an error and want to handle the error instead of rollback

Comment: @dave - Ok aha now I understood what you meant. Thank you! :-)